# Parsing with requests generated from csv?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I made a Python program that reads my csv file of gene access numbers, and I tried to make requests pull up 335 URLs based on each gene access number, but I got an:

InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '[the urls...]'

My code was:

```
import urllib.request as urllib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def fresh_soup(url):    
'''
Collects and parses the page source from a given url, returns the parsed page source 
- url : the url you wish to scrape
'''
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib.Request(url,headers=hdr) 
source = urllib.urlopen(req,timeout=10).read() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,"lxml")  

return soup
###


import csv

result = []
for line in open("C:/Projects/NCBI Scraper project/geneAccNumbers.txt"):
result.append(line.split('/t'))

csv = open("C:/Projects/NCBI Scraper project/geneAccNumbers.txt", 'r')
for gene in csv.readline().split('/t'):
url = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/' + gene + '.1?report=fasta'


def build_url(gene):
return 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/' + gene + '.1?report=fasta'

genes_urls = [build_url(gene) for gene in csv]


print(genes_urls)

import requests

r = requests.get(genes_urls)
```

Is there something I can do to make it correctly request every url?

On a side note: I think some of the URLs generated have backforwards and forwards slashes in their name, but when I manually copy it into a browser, it responds like it wasn't even a problem and still gets me the page(s) I want. Should I still try to make it all one type of slash?

Comment: You can't call `get` on a list of URLs. You have to loop `for url in genes_url` and call `get` on each one. (And then do something with it.)

Comment: For 335 URLs I would suggest to look for some parallel solutions, `asyncio` and `aiohttp` for example

Comment: Can you add some sample URLs in file for reference?